# Do we still need to use __init__.py in 2020 in python packages?

Tags: python, import, package, python-module

I'm new to python and have read that we must always include ***__init__.py*** in a python package, and that's the only way to treat it as a python package, so I tried creating a package with sub directories and tried importing the modules with and without ***__init__.py*** but got same results, so now I'm confused that if it still works then why do we still need to add it? is this a thing of past? was it only necessary in older versions of python or is it something else that I'm missing?

Comment: The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__ variable, described later.

explanation from python.org

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages